# Android ROOM INSERT in pre-populated database

Tags: java, android, database, android-room, auto-increment

So, in my app I have a pre-populated database (I used SQLiteStudio to add the data and set the primary key on auto-increment for each table). 
I want to add more rows in the one table of the database (that has already some data).

**The problem is** that the primary key is not auto-incremented and I think this happens because there is already some data in the table.
      Does anyone know how to make the `autogenerate` work for pre-populated databases? Or the only solution is to manually add the ID, by selecting `max(ID)` from the table and adding 1 to it ?

*Thank you in advance for taking some time to read this!*

One of these tables is `Users` and I put the autogenerated pk:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class Users_table {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int userID;

// the rest of the code 
}
```

I also checked and the `@Insert` method is called but I saw in logs that **all userIDs are 0**.